# Magento 2 - Cant place orders after migration

Tags: magento2, orders, payment, magento2-migration-tool, magento-2.1.3

i experienced another bug (?) after migrating from `Magento 1.9.1.0` to `Magento 2.1.3` within the Checkout.

**Steps to reproduce:**

1) Setup a store in `Magento 1.9.1.0` with some products and customer

2) Migrate that Store to `Magento 2.1.3` - using the Magento Data migration tool

3) Add custom payment methods and shipping rates - actually migrated from `1.9.1.0`

4) Login to an existing customer account and order something.

**What should happen**

- Order gets placed

**What happens**

- `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 (Bad Request) - www.host.domain/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information`
- `POST host.domain/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information 400 (Bad Request)`

Anyone who can help me with this ? A store with no orders cant be a working store :)

Thanks in andance

**EDIT**

Log from `debug.log`:

```
[2017-02-08 09:47:44] main.DEBUG: cache_invalidate:  {"method":"POST","url":"http://host.domain/rest/default/V1/carts/mine/payment-information","invalidateInfo":{"tags":["catalog_product_12265","FPC"],"mode":"matchingTag"},"is_exception":false} []
```

**EDIT 2**

After some more testing and google'ing i found out that the error only appears on migrated customers. With a new created one the order went straight through without any problems.

**EDIT 3**

After editing the `PaymentInformationManagement.php` to display the actuall error i finally get a `exception.log` with the following content:

```
[2017-02-14 11:04:51] main.CRITICAL: PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '201600769-1' for key 'SALES_ORDER_INCREMENT_ID_STORE_ID' in /usr/www/users/nullnp/de_nullbar/vendor/magento/zendframework1/library/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:228
```

So my guess was to increase the increament ID but i cant figure out where..

Comment: Check your exception log, it should contain the origin reason of exception because `payment-information` WEB API provides only high-level errors.

Comment: no `exception.log` inside the `var/log` folder. Problem is still existend

Comment: @MarcelH. Did you solved this issue, i tried so much of googled still no proper solution.

Comment: @zus Check the accepted answer - That was my solution back in the days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved**

I change the increment number for every store-view that i got.

PhpMyAdmin -> `sequence_order_` -> Operations -> Tableoptions -> `AUTO_INCREMENT`

Answer (score 0):

First of all

1)flush the cache

2)setup upgrade using "**php bin/magento setup:upgrade**" command.

3)**and enable the cache.
it will solve your issue.**

Comment: sadly it didnt solve my issue. Still got the same error. I flushed the cache, disabled it, run the setup:upgrade command and re-enabled the cache.